# How do I use Java's bitwise operators in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

Java has *binary-or* `|` and *binary-and* `&` operators:

```
int a = 5 | 10;
int b = 5 & 10;
```

They do not seem to work in Kotlin:

```
val a = 5 | 10;
val b = 5 & 10;
```

How do I use Java's bitwise operators in Kotlin?

Comment: What about `|=`?

Comment: For everybody who needs bitwise operators in Kotlin: please vote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1440

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You have named functions for them.

Directly from [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#bitwise-operations)

> Bitwise operations are represented by functions that can be called in infix form. They can be applied only to `Int` and `Long`.

for example:

```
val x = (1 shl 2) and 0x000FF000
```

Here is the complete list of bitwise operations:

```
shl(bits) – signed shift left (Java's <<)
shr(bits) – signed shift right (Java's >>)
ushr(bits) – unsigned shift right (Java's >>>)
and(bits) – bitwise and
or(bits) – bitwise or
xor(bits) – bitwise xor
inv() – bitwise inversion
```

Comment: Note that bitwise inversion would be used like `5.inv()`, not as infix like the others

Comment: Note that bitwise inversion is also known as bitwise complement or bitwise NOT

Comment: I find it odd that Kotlin decided bitwise operators would get these awkwardly named functions, while the actual boolean operators like and and or still got operators. It's a bit backwards isn't it? If anything I'd want these to stay as the symbols and the boolean operators to become words.

Comment: @Hakanai hard agree. It was especially hard for me when coming over from a language like python where I was accustomed to writing expressions like `if (condition1 or condition2) and condition3: do this`. This is much more intuitive and just naturally easy to understand.

Answer (score 26):

you can do this in Kotlin

```
val a = 5 or 10;
val b = 5 and 10;
```

here list of operations that you can use

```
shl(bits) – signed shift left (Java's <<)
shr(bits) – signed shift right (Java's >>)
ushr(bits) – unsigned shift right (Java's >>>)
and(bits) – bitwise and
or(bits) – bitwise or
xor(bits) – bitwise xor
inv() – bitwise inversion
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported, but most probably will be by the new Kotlin compiler **K2**, see [Roman Elizarov's comment on the YouTrack issue KT-1440](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1440#focus=Comments-27-5629291.0-0).

See [KT-46756](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46756) for the upcoming alpha release and keep an eye on the [roadmap](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/roadmap.html#roadmap-details).

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

Java:

```
 byte dataHigh = (byte) ((data[byteOffset] & 0xF0) >> 4);
```

Kotlin

```
val d = (data[byteOffset] and 0xF0.toByte())
val dataHigh = (d.toInt() shr 4).toByte()
```